# EditText is hidden by the keyboard

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-edittext, android-framelayout

I have my application that is a tabbed app.
For the fragment that keeps the main fragments I used FrameLayout:

```
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/actualtabcontent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tabContainer"
    android:background="@color/white"/>
```

Each new fragment is created by using LinearLayout and when needed, I used ScrollView inside LinearLayout.
The problem is that, when my layout is a big one and I have EditText at the bottom of the screen, the keyboard is open over the EditText, and I cannot see it anymore.

I tried to add this in my manifest file:

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="----"
```

with all possible combinations and nothing worked until now.

Also, I added

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true
```

in the FrameLayout, that is the parent of all my fragments and also, it did not work.

I am expecting that, when the keyboard opens, that the View to be scrolled so the focused EditText to pe at the top of the Keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You assigned `windowSoftInputMode` as "----",

this is creating problem

try adding this

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

in your manifest file for the activity you are using

something like this

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" >
</activity>
```

Comment: "----" was just a placeholder, to highlight that I used it with many combinations.

Comment: Please try the above combination and let me know if it works

Comment: Can you please show the XML file containing EditText?

Comment: where you put this line `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" ` in manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest put this in your perticular activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem  was that all the proprieties of the MainActivity were not in the manifest file, they were added as Attributes on the View class, as I am using Xamarin.Android.

All the rules that I`ve added until now were added on another activity.

Comment: Thank you for sharing, you could marked it. This will make answer searching easier and beneficial to community members.